# Pass a value from selected option to another option

Tags: javascript, html-select

what i'm trying to do is to pass a value from selected option that i have choose, to another option tag in another form by clicking a checkbox

[from this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvCEp.png)

[click a checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYavO.png)

and then
[to this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwkLb.png)

what i have done is:

```
$('input[name=sameKTP]').change(function() {
    if($('input[name="sameKTP"]').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
        $('#domcAddressDataSubmit').val($('#ktpAddressDataSubmit').val());
        $('#domcStateId').val($('#ktpStateId').val());
        $('#domcCityId').val($('#ktpCityId').val());
        $('#domcDistrictId').val($('#ktpDistrictId').val());
        $('#domcSubDistrictId').val($('#ktpSubDistrictId ').val());
        $('#domcRtDataSubmit').val($('#ktpRtDataSubmit').val());
        $('#domcRwDataSubmit').val($('#ktpRwDataSubmit').val());
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
        $('#domcAddressDataSubmit').val('');
        $('#domcStateId').val('');
        $('#domcCityId').val('');
        $('#domcDistrictId').val('');
        $('#domcSubDistrictId').val('');
        $('#domcRtDataSubmit').val('');
        $('#domcRwDataSubmit').val('');
    }
});
```

this code could only pass a value that have a type=text field not a value in option tag

How can I do this the best way?

Comment: when the form 1 to form 2 the page is redirect/post page to another page ? or this 2 form in the one page ?

Comment: @FikriF this is on the same page, it's just separated with step by step form

Comment: i dont know, your code looks fine, maybe you need add more example html code

Comment: yes that's what i thought too, because there is no error in console. should i put at least one field from the form?

Comment: yeah just put example one field from form 1 & form 2